# Как сделать чтобы после 23 шел 0 час в цикле?

Tags: php

Как сделать так, чтобы после 23 шел 0 час в цикле?

```
for($y = $start_hour, $cnt = $start_hour + 12; $y < $cnt; $y++) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Остаток от деления на 24 вполне подойдет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как сказал *Владимир Мартьянов*

```
for($y = $start_hour, $cnt = $start_hour + 12; $y < $cnt; $y++) {
  $hourInLoop = $y % 24;
```